# Block core/list defined outside any layout handle

Tags: layout, bug, ce-1.7.0.2

What does this definition of a block core/list mean, at the very end of `checkout.xml`, Magento CE 1.7.0.2:

```
[...]
        </checkout_onepage_failure>
    <block type="core/list" name="additional.product.info"/>
</layout>
```

Just a bug?

Comment: looks like. block outside of a layout handle makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug - in Magento 2 this is not there any more.

Comment: You should report this bug :)

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: I gave up on reporting Mage 1 bugs --- the Mage 2 development turns out to be much more involving the community.

Comment: @Alex Don't forget to come back and mark your self answers as "best answer".